# Keyboard not working in Among us (wine) on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, wine

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell Vostro 3546.

```
uname -a

Linux vaishnavi-laptop 4.15.0-124-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:54:43 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to play Among Us. I followed the instructions of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSa5uAqzQvE).
But as you know we need to first enter name to play, but **MY KEYBOARD IS NOT WORKING !!!**. FYI, when i use folio views (using wine) keyboard works.
What I have tried (with no luck):

1. In `winecfg` enabling `emulate a virtual desktop`
2. In `winecfg` disabling `allow the window manager to control the windows`
3. In `regedit` creating new entry "UseTakeFocus" with value "N" in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\X11 Driver`

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

```
Applications --> Language Support
```

I changed "Keyboard input method system" from `ibus` to `none`

Works like a charm!